# how do i use the success function with an $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I don't understand how the success function works in a $.ajax call with jquery.

for instance

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: "function=1",
    success: function(data,response,jqxhr){
         useReturnData(data /* ??? not sure how to use the data var */ );
    }
};
```

ajax.php:

```
 <?php
      if ($_REQUEST['function'] == '1'){
            $string = "this is the data i want to return and use";
      }
 ?>
```

how do i use that data within the success function?  No where seems to explain what the data parameter is, they just seem to use it ambiguously.

another side question, is the data: "function=1" related to the data as a parameter for the success function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` variable contains the output of your php file, so if in your php file you do:

```
echo "<p>success</p>";
```

`data` will contain `<p>success</p>`.

In your example you would change your php file to:

```
<?php
      if ($_REQUEST['function'] == '1'){
            $string = "this is the data i want to return and use";
      }

      // other stuff...

      echo $string;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The content of the `data` parameter depends on the type of the response.  If the `Content-Type` is `application/json`, then it's parsed as JSON.  If it's `text/html` or similar, the content is HTML.  In your case, it looks like you're returning text.  If you make your `Content-Type` header `text/plain` or similar, then `data` should just be a string.

To answer your second question, the `data` property for the Ajax request is something different; it specifies the *request* data that is sent.  In other words, it's the query string if you have a `GET` request, and the post "form" variables if it's a `POST` request.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is whatever is returned by the server side script, so in this case it would be

```
this is the data i want to return and use
```

Providing the `if()` condition is met.

Nobody really says what `data` contains because it can contain various different things, although it's always a string. Sometimes it's HTML, sometimes it's JSON and sometimes just a return message.

In your case, `data` will just be a string *providing you echo the string out in your server side script*.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to load the data into some placeholder element (div?)
E.G.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: "function=1",
    success: function(data,response,jqxhr){
         $('div.selector').load(data);
    }
};
```

Comment: Either you do given the URL to [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) directly (no .ajax() call needed then), or use `.html()` or so for injecting. This seems kind of mixed up.